# Is there any way allowing SSH local port forwarding to certain ports only

Tags: ssh, openssh

PermitOpen allows to do filtering based on both IPAddress and port.I want filtering for certain ports only.Does PermitOpen support that or there any other way we can do that?

Comment: That sounds like a firewall rule to me.

Comment: I want to disallow external access to telnet service which is on port 22 via ssh port forwarding.Internally telnet should be allowed. IP on which telnet is running is dynamic so it can not be used in PermitOpen .So I want to restrict port 22 somehow via port forwarding.

Comment: I doubt openssh will do this but a firewall, such as iptables, should let you restrict a certain port to local traffic only. Another option would be to tell telnet to only bind port 22 for localhost